# Comparar dos cadenas de strings

Tags: python

Mi código:

```
Texto1 = "BANANA CASA LUNA"
Texto2 = "ARENA FLOR GONDOLA"

Texto1 = Texto1.split(); Texto2 = Texto2.split()
Texto3 = ""
for i in range(len(Texto1)):
    for j in range(len(Texto2)):
        if Texto1[i] < Texto2[j]:
            Texto3 = Texto3 + Texto1[i]
        else:
            Texto3 = Texto3 + Texto2[j]
print(Texto3)
```

Salida:

```
ARENABANANABANANAARENACASACASAARENAFLORGONDOLA
```

El objetivo del codigo es comparar dos cadenas y ordenarla (de menor a mayor) en una tercera.

De primeras, el código funciona. El problema es que no puedo solventar que la palabra que sea usada, por ejemplo, "ARENA" , no sea utilizada mas adelante. Si esto se cumpliera el resultado deberia ser este:

```
#Cadena con palabras ordenadas.
ARENABANANACASAFLORGONDOLALUNA
#con split
ARENA BANANA CASA FLOR GONDOLA LUNA
```

Si existe otra forma de hacerlo de formas mas eficiente se agradeceria el aporte, pero es mas importante resolver el que se mostro.

Recalco que no se debe utilizar la funcion sort. Y, cualquier pregunta... pregunte.

Comment: solo verifica si ya esta en la lista con un `if palabra in lista: continue`

Answer (score 1):

La solución es simple, usando *bubble sort*:

```
def bubble(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista) - 1):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lista)):
            if lista[i] > lista[j]:
                lista[i], lista[j] = lista[j], lista[i]
    return lista
```

Esta función recibe una lista y la devuelve ordenada de menor a mayor.

El algoritmo consiste en comparar el elemento actual contra todos los que le siguen. Si hay un elemento menor, se intercambian y se sigue comparando. Esto garantiza que al final de una pasada, el elemento actual sea el menor de todos los que siguen.

Para ordenar la lista completa, se parte desde el primer elemento hasta el penúltimo, repitiendo el procedimiento en cada paso.

Para intercambiar en un solo paso dos elementos, aprovechamos el hecho de que las expresiones del lado derecho son evaluadas antes de realizar las asignaciones al lado izquierdo, por lo que

```
a, b = b, a
```

intercambia los dos valores en un solo paso, sin necesidad de variables intermedias.

#### Aplicación

El problema ahora se reduce a formar la lista antes de ordenarla.

`Texto1.split()` produce una lista

```
['BANANA', 'CASA', 'LUNA']
```

Hago lo mismo con `Texto2.split()` y obtengo dos listas que quiero unir en una, asi:

```
[Texto1.split(), Texto2.split()]
```

que resulta en:

```
[['BANANA', 'CASA', 'LUNA'], ['ARENA', 'FLOR', 'GONDOLA']]
```

que **no** es lo que busco.

Pero en Python tenemos el operador "*" (asterisco), que hace el efecto de reemplazar la lista por sus elementos: donde dice `*lista`, es como si dijera `lista[0], lista[1], ..., lista[n]`

Entonces, arreglando un poco la expresión, tenemos

```
[*Texto1.split(), *Texto2.split()]
```

que resulta en

```
['BANANA', 'CASA', 'LUNA', 'ARENA', 'FLOR', 'GONDOLA']
```

Ahora que tengo la lista, uso `bubble` para obtener una lista ordenada:

```
lista_final = bubble([*Texto1.split(), *Texto2.split()])
```

#### Demo

```
Texto1 = "BANANA CASA LUNA"
Texto2 = "ARENA FLOR GONDOLA"

print(bubble([*Texto1.split(), *Texto2.split()]))
```

produce:

```
['ARENA', 'BANANA', 'CASA', 'FLOR', 'GONDOLA', 'LUNA']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Tengo dos preguntas... porque (len(lista) - 1)  y  (i + 1, len(lista)) . Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Quiero comparar cada elemento contra los siguientes por la derecha. Necesito dos elementos para comparar, por lo que la última iteración comparara el penúltimo (ubicado en len(lista) - 1) contra el último (len(lista)). Ejecuta el algoritmo a mano y podrás apreciarlo.